# How to compile and run a csharp file using dockerfile

Tags: c#, docker

How can I compile a single file (or several) for a simple csharp application using a docker file? My goal is to create a small csharp repl similar to the w3 schools one [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_compiler.php). I've taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769324/how-to-create-run-net-core-console-app-in-docker) but it does not suit my needs. I do not have a .csproj file, I am starting with a simple main.cs file like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I would like to know I can take the above code as a string and use a dockerfile to compile and run it to get the output. Specifically, what base image can I use and do I need to install any other packages before I can do this? The dockerfile below is taken from the other stack overflow question which seems reasonable but I don't want to compile an asp.net program.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY <your app>.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore <your app>.csproj

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<your app>.dll"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the command `dotnet new console` to create a basic console app project and then copy your file on top of the generated Program.cs file to replace it.

I've taken the liberty of replacing your .NET core 2.2 images with .NET 6.0 ones, as the 2.2 ones aren't supported anymore.

If you name your file with the code in it 'MyFile.cs' and use this Dockerfile, it should work

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet new console
COPY MyFile.cs Program.cs
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

Build and run with

```
docker build -t testimage .
docker run --rm testimage
```

With the changes made to .NET 6 you no longer need a lot of the boilerplate C# code, so you can also reduce your program file to a single line

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

Comment: @cbutler I added a comment about reducing the C# file at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you change your approach: Create a full Webapp and use the CSharpCodeProvider. You can read more about the CSharpCodeProvider here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/compile-code-using-compiler

Comment: Why a _"Webapp"?_

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @MickyD or a Container with a REST Api to send the code as text. It doesn't really matter. Instead of deploying a Container each time a user wants to compile code

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestions; I actually did built a web app. It is an online code editor which started as an online code editor for react. It has grown to support a lot more and now I am experimenting with support for compiled languages. Check it out and let me know what you think: https://contrived-dev.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @cbutler cool project. but always watch out when compiling and execute code created by others on your machine ;)

Answer (score -1):

.csproj stands there for a reason. To compile .cs file(s) without it, you have to find the corresponding command-line arguments to construct the minimal set of
configurations while compiling (like -I, -D, -L, etc while compiling a C/C++ project), which will cause your project is not familiar with standard IDEs (VS, VSCode) and take more time for transferring how-to-build to your teammates.

In most production-like applications, thing gets complex and you'll soon need a project configuration file. That's why there are Makefile in C/C++ project, pom.xml in Java-Maven project, etc.

IMO, "over" simplifying doesn't make your project simpler. Focusing on how to solve a business problem using the default configuration and minimize/simplify it when there's a need would be a better choice.